# trying to insert the values in a table called user. There are two columns id and primary how to insert the values

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am working on Asp.net using Sql server 2008.I am inserting the values in a table called User.
It has two Columns. UserID, Primary.

How to write the query to insert the value for column name primary.

```
Insert into Users (UserID, Primary) 
Values (123,1);
```

I  am getting error Incorrect syntax near column name 'Primary'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primary is a key word in sql server just wrap it with sqare brackets `[]`

```
Insert into Users (UserID, [Primary]) 
Values (123,1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to just try escaping it properly ie:

```
Insert into Users ("UserID", "Primary") Values (123,1);
```